# php/laravel | Как после редирекста со страницы передать данные на ту страницу

Tags: laravel

На странице 'create' мы получаем данные из формы и перенаправляем на страницу 'store' что сохранит эти данные в бд, после переадресовываем на страницу 'create', после этой переадресации хочу что-бы на странице 'create' выводилось сообщение что данные успешно загружены.
Сложно передать весь код из за того что он по разным файлам. Вот функция код функции store, что делает переадресацию:

```
 public function store() {
    $postData = request()->validate([
        'info' => 'max:40|min:1',
        'description' => 'min:1|max:255'
    ]);
    posts::create($postData);
    $isDone = 'done ^)';
    return redirect()->route('crud.create')->with($isDone);
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать следующее

```
public function store() {
    $postData = request()->validate([
        'info' => 'max:40|min:1',
        'description' => 'min:1|max:255'
    ]);
    posts::create($postData);

    return redirect(route('crud.create'))->with('success', 'Поздравляем запись создана!'); //нейминг в with делай произвольный.
}
```

Затем в шаблонизаторе blade выведи текст который ты вписал в with через

```
@if(session('success'))
   <p>{{ session('success') }}</p>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Делается всё довольно просто.

Во первых. Не относится к ответу на вопрос `posts::create($postData);` Почему модель с маленькой буквы и во множественном числе? не надо так...

Во вторых все данные сохраняются в сессию когда помещаются в метод `with` то есть доступны так: `session('key')`. Вы можете их вывести на вашем шаблоне.

```
@if(session('key'))
    <span>{{ session('key') }}</span>
@endif
```

В третьих при передачи в `with` лучше передавайте массив. Например так: `->with(['message' => 'Сохранено'])`. или используйте функцию `compact`